# Specializing only a part of a template function's implementation

Tags: c++, templates, boost, runtime, compile-time

I'm wondering if it is anyhow possible to partially specialize a templated method behaviour in case one of the template parameter it's of a certain type.

```
template<class T>
void Foo(T& parameter)
{
    /* some generic - all types - stuff */

    If(T is int) // this is pseudo-code, typeinfo? Boost?
    {
        /* some specific int processing which might not compile with other types */
    }

    /* again some common stuff */
}
```

Any suggestion is welcome.
Thanks

Comment: I've edited the title because the term 'partial specialization' means something completely different from what's being asked about here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you only want to specialize a part of the function then you simply have to factor out the part of the function with specialized implementations:

```
template<class T>
void Bar(T &t) {}

void Bar(int &i) {
    /* some specific int processing which might not compile with other types */
}


template<class T>
void Foo(T &t) {
    /* some generic - all types - stuff */

    Bar(t);

    /* again some common stuff */
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Sure:

```
// helper funciton
template <class T>
void my_helper_function(T& v)
{
  // nothing specific
}

void my_helper_function(int& v)
{
  // int-specific operations
}

// generic version
template <class T>
void Foo(T& v)
{
  /* some generic - all types - stuff */

  my_helper_function(v);

  /* again some common stuff */
}
```

Comment: Wouldnt it be better to overload than specialize?

Comment: Flexo is right. Why specialize? It's much clearer if you just provide an `int` overload.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can provide *specializations* of template functions (just not *partial* specializations). For a member function you will need to define the specialization at namespace level after the class containing the template.

If what you mean is that only part of the function should be specialized, you cannot do that directly, but you can create another templated function that implements that part of the logic, specialize it and call it from your template. The compiler will use the single version of the `Foo` template and the appropriate version of the `FooImplDetail` function.